# ListView Item Positioning

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, listviewitem

I have a list of `GraphItems` which I would like to display on the screen using a `ListView` (I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it) but the rows themselves should be positioned according to `GraphItem.posX` and `GraphItem.posY`

I made one custom adapter to handle the data and to set the position of the view, using `row.setX` and `row.setY` where row is the `convertView` but the problem is:

[image][image]

The click area still remains at the 'old' position.

I already tried to use the `setLayoutParams` to set the margins but I get a cast Exception like `android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams`

I'm open to suggestions about how to do it in a better way, maybe something different from `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `LayoutParams` should be the correct technique. Your cast exception can be solved by using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instead of using just `LayoutParams`.

Also, what are you using to handle clicks, `onItemClickListener()`?

Comment: Hey Wenger, as you may see I'm using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` already. And yes I'm using `onItemCliclListener()` as handler.